# How to change this product carousel into 1 row per item instead of 3 rows per item?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

Hello everyone my current product carousel is currently set for 3 items per row (and 2 for mobile) but I would like to narrow it down to 1 item per row.

How would I be able to code this in order to get 1 item per row?

Current product carousel:
[image]

Desired product carousel:

[image: Desired product carousel:]

here is my code:

```
     * Product carousel

 */

$( '.sober-product-carousel' ).each( function () {
    var $carousel = $( this ),
        columns = parseInt( $carousel.data( 'columns' ), 10 ),
        autoplay = parseInt( $carousel.data( 'autoplay' ), 10 ),
        loop = $carousel.data( 'loop' );
    autoplay = autoplay === 0 ? false : autoplay;
    $carousel.find( 'ul.products' ).addClass( 'owl-carousel' ).owlCarousel( {
        items          : columns,
        autoplay       : !!autoplay,
        autoplayTimeout: autoplay,
        loop           : loop === 'yes',
        pagination     : true,
        navigation     : false,
        slideSpeed     : 300,
        paginationSpeed: 500,
        rtl            : !!( soberData && soberData.isRTL && soberData.isRTL === '1' ),
        responsive     : {
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            360:{
                items:2
            },
            767:{
                items:columns
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I could probably give a clearer answer if you post the markup.  It seems you could streamline a lot of this if you only want one item

```
$( '.sober-product-carousel' ).each( function () {

    var $carousel = $( this ),

        columns = parseInt( $carousel.data( 'columns' ), 10 ),

        autoplay = parseInt( $carousel.data( 'autoplay' ), 10 ),

        loop = $carousel.data( 'loop' );



    autoplay = autoplay === 0 ? false : autoplay;



    $carousel.find( 'ul.products' ).addClass( 'owl-carousel' ).owlCarousel( {

        items          : 1,

        autoplay       : !!autoplay,

        autoplayTimeout: autoplay,

        loop           : loop === 'yes',

        pagination     : true,

        navigation     : false,

        slideSpeed     : 300,

        paginationSpeed: 500,

        rtl            : !!( soberData && soberData.isRTL && soberData.isRTL === '1' ),

    } );

} );
```

EDIT: I'd also add that you are using the Owl Carousel plugin:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

EDIT2: If responsive is required:

```
responsive     : {

            0:{

                items:1

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering me. But I am not quite sure what you mean by posting the mark up and streamlining it? Thank you for informing me that I have the owl plugin. So you are saying I should just remove  `360:{

                items:2

            },

            767:{

                items:columns

            }` ?

Comment: @EricSand I think that should work.  By markup, I mean html.  I assume there's some elements with classes of 'sober-product-carousel' and 'ul.products' etc...